# Kernel panic after using html5 video in chrome

Tags: video, google-chrome, netflix, html5

I'm using chrome to watch Netflix on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04. It lets me watch video for a while (30 sec up to 20 min.) and than it hungs up the system permanently. The same problem occurs while watching html5 video on all the websites. 
I can use Chromium or Firefox and there is no such problem. Unfortunately Chrome is the only one that allows me to watch Netflix. 
Do you know any solution to the problem?
Thanks